# NSManagedContext becoming nil after save

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

I am saving a managed object context using the code below.

```
var obj = try decoder.decode(modelType, from: jsonData)
obj.save()
```

This inserts the entity in main context and saves the main context. This usually works good. My `entity` has the required `unique constraints` needed for maintaining uniqueness. But in case there is already a entry in the context after I run `obj.save()` the `managedObjectContext` for the `managedObject` becomes `nil`

Whereas I have defined a `NSMergePolicy` hence I expect the merge to complete successfully.

How to make sure do not loose reference of the context after saving.

Answer (score 0):

Any `NSMergePolicy` besides `error` is wrong.  It is asking core-data to lose data, you just get to decide which.  Most constraints are wrong.  It is asking business logic to be in database errors.  Instead of validating your data before you enter it, it is throwing an error when trying to save it instead.  That is much harder to deal with.

This is not to say that you can't make a setup with a merge policy and constraints work.  But I have yet to see a setup where these tools made the application easier to program to maintain.